# How to retrieve a Firebase Storage image stream in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I've got a few photo's I've uploaded into my firebase storage under a file called 'photos' and I want to be able to retrieve them onto my app through a stream. I have done this before through Firebase cloud database by tapping into the Firestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots() property in my StreamBuilder, but I don't know how to access the firebase storage snapshots and upload them as a stream into my app.

This was my code for the messages snapshot, I hope it helps:

```
final _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  void messagesStream() async {
    await for (var message in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()){
      for (var snapshot in message.documents){
        print(snapshot.data);
      }
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[

            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){

                  if (!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,),
                    );
                  } else {
                final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                for (var message in messages){
                  final messageText = message.data['text'];
                  final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

                  final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                  messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(children: messageWidgets,);
              }

            }
            ),
),
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out you can't create a stream from the firebase storage, but what I could do was, in my firebase cloud database, start a new collection called 'my_collection' and in a new document, create an auto-ID, with a field called 'image' which is a string, with an http reference to an image that is on the internet, or one you can upload to the internet (this is what I did on imgur.com, credit to them)! Here is my code below, I hope it helps others! If it doesn't, have a look at this code written by iampawan, he helped me a tonne!

https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterWithFirebase

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}



class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {

  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
  List <DocumentSnapshot> myList;

  final CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection('my_collection');
  final DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('my_collection').document('GFWRerw45DW5GB54p');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        myList = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
  }

@override
void dispose() {
  subscription?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return myList != null ?
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: myList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
          String imgPath = myList[index].data['image'];
          return MyCard(assetImage: Image.network(imgPath), function:
              (){
            if (imgPath == myList[0].data['image']){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyMenu.id);
            } else if (imgPath == myList[1].data['image']){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, YourMenu.id);
            } else if (imgPath == myList[2].data['image']){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, HisMenu.id);
            } else if (imgPath == myList[3].data['image']){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, HerMenu.id);
            }
            },);
        })
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );

  }
}
```

Just to note, MyCard is it's own page with it's own constructor that requires an assetImage and a function for the user to be pushed to a new screen:

```
MyCard({@required this.assetImage, @required this.function});
final Image assetImage;
final Function function;
```